# Quick and dirty way to run a process more than once

Tags: bash, process, scripting

I am looking for very simple bash script that would allow me to launch a process a few times. What's essential to me is that after the processes terminate, everything will clean up automatically.

Intended usage:

```
bash multiplerun.sh 5 executable.sh parameters_to_executable
```

I could probably write it myself, but it would take me so long that I've decided to ask experts; I'm very little skilled at using *ix systems.

EDIT: Oh, and I forgot to add that I want to run them in parallel - running them one after another is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Isn't there some tension between "*quick and dirty*" and "*everything cleaned up automatically*"?  The task is pretty difficult if the processes work on files, btw...

Comment: They don't work on files - they're only used as dummy clients connecting to a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something that will launch your programs in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$1
command=$2
shift 2

for ((i=0;i<count;i++)); do
  $command "$@" &
done
wait
echo done
```

The wait instruction should prevent zombies to show up. If your programs do not need a tty, you can replace the loop with:

```
for ((i=0;i<count;i++)); do
  nohup $command "$@" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

That way, the processes will be detached from your shell.

Comment: As for the cleanup - I meant that there won't be any zombie processes, screens or anything running. I'm gonna run the script more than once and I didn't want to end up with 1000 zombies just sitting there.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
seq 5 | parallel -N0 executable.sh parameters_to_executable
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1